# Is there functionality in JPA/Spring/Hibernate/etc similar to JPA's @PrePersist that would allow changes to related entities?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I need to store normalized (i.e. without special characters etc.) variants of some of the `String` fields of some entities.

An example:

```
@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String make;
    private String model;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CAR_ID")
    private Set<NormalizedField> normalizedFields = new HashSet();

    private Set<NormalizedField> createNormalizedFields(Car car) {
        Set<NormalizedField> normalized = normalize(car);
        this.normalizedFields.clear();
        this.normalizedFields.addAll(normalized);
    }

    // I would use this approach, but it doesn't allow
    // changes to related entities.
    // @PreCreate
    // public void onCreate() {
    //     createNormalizedFields();
    // }
}

@Entity
public class NormalizedField {
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String fieldName;
   private String normalizedValue;
}
```

It would be convenient if the normalized values were automatically (re)created whenever the `Car` entity is persisted. Is there a way to trigger the creation method automatically?

Using `@PrePersist, @PreUpdate`... is obviously not an option as it doesn't allow changes to related entities.

Spring AOP is not used in the project, so I would rather avoid introducing it for now. But it's an option anyways.

The application is huge, and managing the normalized values 'manually' would require quite a bit of work, hence I leave it as the last option.

Comment: Use a custom `UserType` or `AttributeConverter` that does that.

Comment: @M.Deinum, it appears that `AttributeConverter` is not to be used for relationship attributes. Besides, the attribute itself doesn't contain the data for conversion, instead the parent entities' state is needed.

The same problem of access to parent's state exists for custom `UserType` as well.

Comment: My bad. I should have been reading more careful.  It shouldn’t the prepersist just work? The main problem I see is that you are clearing the collection and add everything again, where you should update an existing one. Also you should implement proper equals amd hashcode for using those in a Set.

Comment: PrePersist doesn't work because it's not allowed to change **relation** state in it. Only non-relation properties.

Comment: Interesting; a few questions come to mind: (1) What is the nature of `normalize()`? If it depends only on the state of the current entity, maybe the normalized values do not need to be persisted. Instead, do the normalization on the fly when needed (and maybe cache the result to a `@Transient` field). (2) Isn't it more appropriate to execute the normalization in the application logic, if it depends on state outside of the `Car` entity? (3) Does the `NormalizedField` have to be an entity? Can you model it as a collection of persisted values (maybe that works on `PrePersist`)?

Comment: (1) normalize only depends on entity state, but must be available in the database for native SQL queries. (2) I'm afraid some places might be missed now and later on, and the normalized values are absolutely mandatory (3) it has to be an entity to be stored in a separate table

PS. I've found a solution, going to post it soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to post this half-answer here ('half' because it provides a workaround with restrictions).

In some cases `org.hibernate.Interceptor` can be used to manage child entities whenever the parent entity is changed.

But there are restrictions: the javadoc says `Session` is not to be used in the `Interceptor`. JPA repository methods, JPQL or HQL calls are intercepted by the same `Interceptor` in a loop. Even native queries get intercepted unless you set `FlushMode.COMMIT` or `FlushMode.MANUAL` (and maybe some other).

The above means you'll probably have to use the datasource directly. I don't remember exactly how, but Spring provides means to execute queries using datasource directly and within current transaction. In my case it was enough as I had to manage some technical child entities that didn't need a representation as an `Entity`.